# What is the function of "removing doubles UV"

Tags: modeling, uv

I was working with blender and I imported a CAD file.

I was trying to UV unwrap the model, which is high poly (see photos).

Can someone explain to me what the "remove doubles UV" option does?

In my case I just used it and from this

[image]

I got this

[image]

I see there are a lot fewer edges in the UV map but the model stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Doubles UV does exactly what it sounds like.  The unwrapped vertices are combined within a set limit.  For some reason, the **Merge Distance** is not available in the **UV window**... only in the **3D View window**.  This has no effect on the geometry of the mesh, only on the UV.

[image]

From the manual:

> The Remove Doubles UV tool will merge selected UVs within the specified Margin.

Comment: So then is a good idea to use it one time when UV unwrapping? I mean in my example there are a lot of vertices gone...but haven't tested how looks like with a texture. Is there an advantage by havind less vertices in an UV map? Where do I find such an image, like the one you used in your gif?

Comment: @R.Gomez - I just Googled "test UV map" in images.  To be honest, I'm drawing a blank as to the usefulness of this function.  I can't think of a specific circumstance where I would want the UV map "compressed" with respect to the mesh.  In fact, the whole point is to get the UV as 1-to-1 with the mesh as possible.  But there are several vertex functions in the Mesh editing side of things that are also mirrored in the UV window, so I guess more options is better.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very useful function when making textures for game assets.

When modeling game assets you usually get a lot of similar faces that could use the same texture space, so you want to align them on the same spot. But to save even more space, it's a good idea to use the "pack islands" function.

If you haven't merged the UV's with the "remove doubles UV" function, they will get separated again and moved to different parts of the map.